# Input file reading error

Tags: c++

Hi i currently wrote a program but I'm having problems with reading the file. It seems to have read the last line twice, as a result, producing the same results twice.

I had put the getline() function to read the first line, in order to store the string for the variable G.
The rest, I had stored it in a vector of the class object.

basically the file is opened and it performs this loop

```
file.open("bodies1.txt");
getline(file, G1);
....


while(!file.eof)
{
  file >> body;
  bodies.push_back(body);
}
```

this is what the text file look like (this is just a sample. not the actual thing)

```
0.02932
Sun 32 42 53 2 2
Moon 49 32 4 2 1
Jupiter 32 53 2 3 2
```

I really was wondering why it read the last line twice. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JesseGood I agree that the EOF is the problem, I'm not sure that this question is a duplicate of that question however. That answer will solve their problem.

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins: Problems related to the C++ anti-pattern `while(!file.eof)` are very common. Check out how many duplicates are linked to that question.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(!file.eof())
{
  file >> body;
  bodies.push_back(body);
}
```

After reading the last object in to `body`, `eof` is the **next** character. Then

```
file >> body;
```

tries to read it and **fails**. So **whatever was in `body` before is still there** and will be pushed in to the vector.

---

instead you should read like

```
while(file >> body)
{
  bodies.push_back(body);
}
```

This way your while stops as soon as you encounter `eof()` and you will not do an extra push in to the vector.

Comment: ok that makes sense. It's weird how it reads eof? never knew it was a character

Comment: @user2188311 No it is not really about eof(). It is about when it gets read. In the first case it is read in the loop body. So even if you hit eof the rest of the loop still gets executed. Think about it :)